# jQuery .toggle() does not work after text loaded into div

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP MVC 3 page I am trying to use jQuery `.toggle()` to hide and show a text box based on whether a user has clicked on a `checkbox` or not. When the page loads, the text box is hidden. Most of the time the user will put values into a couple separate text boxes and an Ajax call will place a value inside that `div` element's `.text()` property. When the user clicks the check box, I want any value in the `div` to dissapear, and the text box to appear.

Right now, I can make the `div` text appear/reappear just fine. However, the `textbox` will only appear if the ajax call has not been made prior.

Here is the code from the Ajax call.

```
function getDrmTerritory(zipCode, stateCode, channelName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("getTerritory","AgentTransmission")',
        data: { zipCode: zipCode, stateCode: stateCode, channelName: channelName },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "") {
                alert("No Territory Code for " + channelName + " located in " + stateCode + ", " + zipCode);
                $('#territoryName').text("");
                $('#Region').val("");
            } else {
                $('#Region').val(data);
                $('#territoryName').text(data);
                alert("Territory set to " + data);
                window.global = data;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Territory did not get set, please review State/Zip/Market Segment");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the `div`. The Ajax call above is supposed to simply place some text inside the `div`, not the `textbox` itself as that is hidden at this point.

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region)
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field" id="territoryName">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Region, new { style = "display: none;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Region)
    </div>
```

By clicking the `checkbox` in this `div`

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        Override Territory Manually?
    </div>
    <div class="M-display-field" style="padding-right:190px;padding-top:10px;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.OverrideRegionInd)
    </div>
```

this `.click` function is called (this function is inside the `document.ready` function). This click function makes the `#Region` `TextBoxFor<>` control appear reappear. However, like i said earlier, this only works if the `getDrmTerritory` Ajax call has not been made.

```
    $('#OverrideRegionInd').click(function () {
        var region = $.trim($('#territoryName').text());
        if (region != "") {
            $('#territoryName').text("")
        } else {
            $('#territoryName').text(window.global);
        }
        $('#Region').toggle();
    });
```

EDIT

This `.ajaxComplete` call should also be mentioned since it's called everytime after the `GetChannel()` method. It seems like the `$('#territoryName').text("");` line is blowing away the text box from the page, however i can't figure out how to make the text in that `div` element go away and keep the `TextBoxFor<>` control at the same time.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url == "/AgentTransmission/GetChannel") {
        var channel = $.trim($('#channelName').text());
        if ($('#AlignmentM:radio').is(':checked')) {
            if ($('#MailingZip').val() != "" && $('#MailingState').val() != "" && channel != "") {
                getDrmTerritory($('#MailingZip').val(), $('#MailingState').val(), channel);
            } else if (channel != "") {
                $('#territoryName').text("");
                $('#Region').val("");
            }
        }
        else if ($('#AlignmentL:radio').is(':checked')) {
            if ($('#LocationZip').val() != "" && $('#LocationState').val() != "" && channel != "") {
                getDrmTerritory($('#LocationZip').val(), $('#LocationState').val(), channel);
            } else if (channel != "") {
                $('#territoryName').text("");
                $('#Region').val("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the text of the `div`, you need to set the text on the `span`. Otherwise the contents of the `div` are removed after this:

```
$("#territoryName").text("");
```

Instead replace them to work on the validation `span`:

```
$("#territoryName span").text("");
```

and

```
$('#territoryName span').text(data);
```